# Limit of records to show in <lightning:datatable>

Tags: lightning, datatable

I am new to lightning datatable, Using soql query we can get up to 50000 records, but is there any limit to show these records using lightning:datatable in lightning component ? If yes then how many records can be showed on one page without using pagination.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *enforced* limit to how many rows can be put in a table. You will, however, eventually run in to performance problems if you load too much at once. You should always use pagination or infinite scrolling for some reasonable value. You can easily run out of memory or experience a massively laggy user experience. Try to keep your tables smaller than a few hundred rows.